# Is it better to develop a social mobile app like Twitter using Hybrid or Native development?

Tags: mobile

If you are going to develop a social mobile app like Twitter, is it better for a social mobile app to be a hybrid or native app?

Comment: My colleague wrote a post about our experience with Ionic 2 that may help you: http://engineering.pivotal.io/post/writing-an-ionic2-app-for-production/. However, note that broad, opinion-based questions like this are not on topic for SO.

Comment: Very nice article, you helped me a lot. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wish there would be a simple answer.

Why Native?

Pros:

- High Scalability
- High Performance
- Better native control over device

Cons:

- High development time
- UI elements are not so cool
- Learning curve/Knowledge of Native C/Java (Or C# -Xamarin) required
- Specific development tool/resources required

While Hybrid apps also can be an alternative then why Hybrid?

Pros:

- Less development time
- Better UI controls
- Can have generic UI on all different device OS
- Simple
- Knowledge of HTML5/CSS/Jquery/AngularJs is required though

Cons:

- Not great control over device specific tasks(eg. using advance camera or gallery actions requires plug-in)
- Performance is slightly poor (however nowadays everyone has got decent phones with better internet)

You can browse and check for yourself what is most suitable to you:

- http://appvswebsite.com/
- http://www.multidots.com/difference-native-vs-hybrid-android-app-development-2/
- https://www.mobiloud.com/blog/native-web-or-hybrid-apps/

Answer (score 1):

For a social networking application like twitter as you've mentioned I suppose you'd want a wide variety of features in that app.

Building native apps for iOS and Android will give the freedom of adding platform specific functionalities which will in turn enhance user experience.

Some features that are used by default on most of the apps on iOS are not present in android by default. For example, swipe to delete is pretty common and default in iOS while in android people prefer long press to delete.

You won't have this freedom for user capabilities and a better user experience with hybrid apps.

On the other hand hybrid apps will be faster to develop as compared to native apps. 
Another point to take into consideration would be that one would require two developers for native apps for iOS and Android, whereas a single hybrid developer for a multi-platform app.

Hybrid and cross platform apps can save you some time and money at start, but they can't match the performance, usability and sleekness of native apps, so ultimately native is the way, so if you have resources, go native.